# Trouble with freezing rotation on a certain animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on some enemy animations for a combat oriented game in Unity, and am looking for a way to freeze his rotation and motion when he enters a certain state.

The enemy has a boolean variable in his Animator called isAttacking. isAttacking is switched on by code and makes him swing his axe.

Problem is, the AI I coded (with heavy help from a tutorial) makes him rotate if the player is close. I dont want him to rotate during his attack animation.

```
            this.transform.rotation = 
Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                                      Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 
0.1f);
```

This is the piece of code that makes him rotate. This code is activated if the player is within 10 units of him.

I've tried some hodge podgey methods like this:

```
if (Anim.GetBool("isAttacking") == true) {
            this.transform.rotation = 
Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                                      Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 
0.1f);
}
```

I also tried to set the rigidbody to disable rotation for a time

```
if (Anim.GetBool("isAttacking") == true) {
Rigid.freezeRotation = true;
}
else {
Rigid.freezeRotation = false;
}
```

Neither of which worked for me.

I haven't pursued the freezing of his motion.

This is the code that runs the AI

```
private void Update()
{

    if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 10)
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        direction.y = 0;

        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                                  Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);

        Anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
        if (direction.magnitude > 1)
        {
                this.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.07f);
                Anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                Anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);                
        }

        else
        {
            Anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
            Anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
        Anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        Anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
    }

}
```

How do I prevent rotation and movement during his attack state?

Comment: Why not make an animation to take care of rotation rather then hardcoding the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this is probably with a Coroutine:

```
IEnumerator StopMovement(float duration){
    this.enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    this.enabled = true;
}
```

`StopMovement` just disables the `Update` void for a number of seconds and enables it again afterwards. Call it whenever you attack:

```
StartCoroutine(StopMovement(1.5f)); //disable Update for 1.5 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I'm home